# Append multiple new values to existing hash key in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash with existing key:

```
my_hash["paths"] = ["tests/**"]
```

I have to append multiple values to the key `paths`.

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
my_hash["paths"] << "new path"
my_hash["paths"] << "an other new path"
... and so on
```

I want to do it in one line. Say, have a list of values that I can then push into the existing key directly.

I'll be glad for the help. Thank You.

Comment: You can use `<<` multiple times in one row since it returns the updated array, `my_hash["paths"] << "new path" << "an other new path"`.

Comment: Great. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: "I want to do it in one line." – What is this obsession with "one line"? In Ruby, you can (almost) always replace linebreaks with semicolons, making it possible to write *every* Ruby program in one line. However, I don't think that's terribly useful, so does everybody keep asking about "one line"? Here's your code in one line: `my_hash["paths"] << "new path"; my_hash["paths"] << "an other new path"` Do you think that is somehow better?

Comment: Sorry for your misunderstanding. I just thought doing same thing again and again would be too lame and if I could add all values at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `push`:

```
my_hash["paths"].push("new path", "an other new path")
```

[**Demo**](https://repl.it/B8ru)

Answer (score 5):

Just for sake of options, here's another way to do this:

```
my_hash["paths"] += ["new path", "an other new path"]
```

Comment: In addition I'd use the [`%W` literal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings): `+= %W(new/path another/new/path)` (path names usually don't contain spaces)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) method, provided your `my_hash['paths']` is an `Array`:

```
my_hash['paths'].concat(paths_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
my_hash["paths"].concat(["new path", "an other new path"])
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By little modifying **[shivam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34308561/append-multiple-new-values-to-existing-hash-key-in-ruby#answer-34308658)** :

```
> my_hash["paths"] |= ["new path", "an other new path", "tests/**", "new path", "an other new path"]
#=> ["tests/**", "new path", "an other new path"]
```

**Note:** This will not allow to push duplicate entry..

### [Demo](https://repl.it/B8sM)